# Unable to get code-behind variables in .aspx page

Tags: asp.net, code-behind

I have this in the code-behind:

```
    private string _doLogin = String.Empty;
    private string _source = String.Empty;
    private string _subId = String.Empty;

    #region public properties
    public string DoLogin
    {
        get { return _doLogin; }
    }
    public string Source
    {
        get { return _source; }
    }
    public string SubId
    {
        get { return _subId; }
    }
    #endregion public properties
```

And this in the .aspx file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var doLogin = "<%= DoLogin %>";
    var source = "<%= Source %>";
    var subId = "<%= SubId %>";
</script>
```

Each <% %> variable has an error attached to it saying it doesn't exist in the current context. I used this method before and it worked just fine. Now it doesn't work and I'm quite perplexed as to what the issue may be.

Comment: Did you actually try to build and run it? Sometimes the editor gets confused.

Comment: Are these properties defined in the same class or do you have a separate class for them ?

Comment: I tried to run it and it gave me a compilation error. I have them in the same class.

Comment: @KeithSalmon, this looks weird, just clean your solution, close and restart visual studio

Comment: Double check the declaration at the top, is it the right class file?

Comment: I had the project opened as a website. I re-opened it as a project/solution and it worked. Thanks, everyone!!!

Answer (score 0):

The answer was to open the project as a project/solution rather than as a website.

(I don't know how to mark this as resolved.)